# How to search a line containing word in file and from that line to end of file should be echo the date using shell script

Tags: shell

```
cat "file.log"| grep -q '2013-11-10'
while read line
do
echo  file_content_time=`echo $line | sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0- 9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/'`
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo comparison_start_date=`date -d "$file_content_time" +%Y%m%d`
fi
done < 'file.log'
```

/* Here I am trying find out the line containing '2013-11-10' and from that line onwards date has to display .*/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initial_time=$(grep -o -m1  "2013-11-10 [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]" file.log)

Answer (score 0):

To output everything from a line containing a pattern up to the end-of-file all you need is

```
awk '/2013-11-10/,/pattern-not-in-file/' file.log
```

Comment: It has to display only dates from the first occurence of  2013-11-10 date to end of file

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/pattern/{p=1}p' your_file
```